# Syncing with Google Cloud SQL fails (AWS connection works)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am looking at Google Cloud SQL as an alternative to  AWS SQL to store data gathered with different measuring devices for my company. We use the software GridVis to use access the internal storage of the devices (Janitza UMG605) via TCP/IP and GridVis then syncs the data stored on the device with the mySQL data base.

The syncing procedure works with an internal company MySQL-server and with the relational database tool of AWS but it is often not able to sync with Google Cloud SQL.

Normally, such an issue could be due to Firewall constraint. But the company servers firewall allows protocols to port 3306. Furthermore sometimes the connection works. It seems to me more like a timeout issue.

Anyone an idea what the issue could be?
Could It be that the connection to the CloudSQL instance is to slow?

I am thankful for any help.

Error message (displayed in gridvis):

```
2018-04-04 15:31:05,699 [executor-baseprosumer_test_google_04_04_18-111-thread-2] INFO de.janitza.pasw.project.api.devices.IProjectDeviceManager p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18 - Device-List-Update from database: 0 added, 1 changed and 0 deleted.
2018-04-04 15:32:04,182 [executor-baseprosumer_test_google_04_04_18-111-thread-3] INFO de.janitza.pasw.project.api.devices.IProjectDeviceManager p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18 - Device-List-Update from database: 0 added, 1 changed and 0 deleted.
2018-04-04 15:33:05,792 [executor-baseprosumer_test_google_04_04_18-111-thread-4] INFO de.janitza.pasw.project.api.devices.IProjectDeviceManager p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18 - Device-List-Update from database: 0 added, 1 changed and 0 deleted.
2018-04-04 15:34:28,759 [executor-baseprosumer_test_google_04_04_18-111-thread-2] INFO de.janitza.pasw.project.api.devices.IProjectDeviceManager p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18 - Device-List-Update from database: 0 added, 1 changed and 0 deleted.
2018-04-04 15:34:59,488 [update-device-info-23-thread-1] WARN de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.services.GlobalValuesReadService  - IOException while reading settings of global values
java.io.IOException: Connection closed without indication.
at de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.ftp.FileService.getFileStream(FileService.java:318)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.services.GlobalValuesReadService.fetchValueList(GlobalValuesReadService.java:139)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.services.GlobalValuesReadService.getGlobalValues(GlobalValuesReadService.java:114)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.services.GlobalValuesService.getGlobalValues(GlobalValuesService.java:55)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.global.CacheImpl.heavyOperation(CacheImpl.java:66)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.global.CacheImpl.heavyOperation(CacheImpl.java:28)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.BaseCache.getDeviceOrExcpetion(BaseCache.java:263)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.BaseCache$2.load(BaseCache.java:362)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.BaseCache$2.load(BaseCache.java:346)
at com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader.reload(CacheLoader.java:94)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3525)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadAsync(LocalCache.java:2321)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.refresh(LocalCache.java:2385)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.refresh(LocalCache.java:4085)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.refresh(LocalCache.java:4825)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.BaseCache.refreshFromDevice(BaseCache.java:338)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.PeriodicUpdateFromDevice.pickOneToRefresh(PeriodicUpdateFromDevice.java:91)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.PeriodicUpdateFromDevice.doRun(PeriodicUpdateFromDevice.java:73)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.impl.base.impl.cache.base.PeriodicRunnable.run(PeriodicRunnable.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:479)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:552)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:601)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.pasv(FTP.java:952)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:755)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1747)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(FTPClient.java:1739)
at de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.ftp.FileService.getFileStream(FileService.java:303)
... 25 common frames omitted
2018-04-04 15:35:24,143 [executor-baseprosumer_test_google_04_04_18-111-thread-1] INFO de.janitza.pasw.project.api.devices.IProjectDeviceManager p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18 - Device-List-Update from database: 0 added, 1 changed and 0 deleted.
2018-04-04 15:36:00,331 [sync-prosumer_test_google_04_04_18-113-thread-1] ERROR de.janitza.pasw.device.jasic.services.StorageService p=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18, d=prosumer_test_google_04_04_18:1, type=UMG605 - Prosumer Testanlage - Error reading data
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs show that GridVis is attempting to use FTP to access the Cloud SQL instance. Cloud SQL does not provide FTP access, which is why this is failing.  Amazon RDS, the AWS equivalent to Cloud SQL, does not offer this either, so this would not work as-is on AWS.

I have two theories for what is different, and how to fix them.

1. Possibly you had GridVis configured differently when you were using RDS, so that it didn't use FTP. If this is the case, then configure GridVis the same and it should work with Cloud SQL. Based on your explanation, I don't think this is the case.
2. Possibly on AWS you didn't use RDS but instead used MySQL on EC2. Maybe with a pre-made image like [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0RA8RN). If you want to do the equivalent of this on GCP, use Google Compute Engine instead of Cloud SQL. You can use a Cloud Launcher image like [this one](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/mysql). On GCE you can install an FTP server like GridVis expects.

Comment: Hi I talked as well to employees of Gridwis, apparently FTP is used to access the device. I am now using HTTP to access the device and everything works fine.

Thanks again for your help.